# Is it Possible To Avoid Yield Farms That Use Leverage?

Tags: proof-of-stake, decentralized-exchange, economics, staking, liquidity-provider

**Are there any Yield Farms (YFs) that do not use leverage or is leverage worked into virtually every YF strategy?**

I'm concerned with the use of borrowing behind the scenes of Yield Farms (YFs) in order to achieve astronomical gains, known as leverage. Although, this may work well as a short-term investment, in the long-term, if the prices decline for a sustained period of time there seems to be a high risk of liquidation of the principal comprising the collateral for the YF.

In addition to leverage, other strategies implemented in YFs are lending and crop rotation.

- Lend

  - Earn APY from collateralized loans
- Crop rotation

  - Switch between different protocols
  - Liquidity pools and mining
  - Governance staking

    - Represent voting participation in a liquidity pool